# Finding the maximum of multiple row "groups" in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, pivot-table

I am trying to find the most recent work date in different rows - original information is from a pivot. The number of entries in the rows differ each time and there are so many groups. I can't figure out a formula that I could drag down and it would work. I would just use MAX all the time but there's too much data. I only want the formula output to show up on the first row/column for each "set" - the result should be in the "most recent work date" column.

Example

| Element | Work Date | Most recent work date (output I need) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JOE 123 2022-02-18 |  |  |
|  | 2022-02-19 |  |
| joe 999 | 2023-03-19 |  |
|  | 2023-03-10 |  |
| Cell 1 | 2024-03-12 |  |
|  |  |  |

I'm also putting in an image, that might make more sense

Thank you!

[Example Image from excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4ZEA.png)

Using MAX formula doesn't work because you can't drag it down - I don't want outputs in every single row, just at the start. Doing MAX by hand doesn't work as there is too much data (don't have time, can physically do it)

Thank you!

Comment: Please share the formula(s) you tried. Also, share whether the result should be in the same row as the element or as the work date. Add this information to your post.

Answer (score 2):

### Retrieving Group Maximums

```
=LET(uData,A2:A21,vData,B2:B21,
    s,SCAN("",uData,LAMBDA(sRes,r,IF(r="",sRes,IF(r=sRes,sRes,r)))),
BYROW(uData,LAMBDA(r,IF(r="","",MAX(FILTER(vData,s=r,""))))))
```

[image]

To return an empty string instead of the 1900 date, you could use:

```
=LET(uData,A2:A21,vData,B2:B21,
    s,SCAN("",uData,LAMBDA(sRes,r,IF(r="",sRes,IF(r=sRes,sRes,r)))),
BYROW(uData,LAMBDA(r,LET(
    m,MAX(FILTER(vData,s=r,"")),
IF(r="","",IF(m=0,"",m))))))
```

Comment: it worked in small batches, once we started to add too many rows the data started being wrong. However the small batches worked so thank you very much!!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Could you share some of your data i.e. post a link to it? I would like to find out what's wrong with the formula.